# Changing background color by button press in GLUT

Tags: opengl, glut

been following a few tutorials and other questions people have been asking on here. Essentially trying to make it when you press the escape key the background colour changes into another colour.

Edited the post with the whole code.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <glut.h>


void render(void);
void keyboard(int key, int x, int y);

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    glutInit(&argc, argv); 
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100); //Position of the window
    glutInitWindowSize(620, 440); //Screen Size
    glClearColor (0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0 );
    glutCreateWindow("Greeting Card");  //Creates the window and names it

    glEnable(GL_BLEND);                                
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA); // Enables Alpha channel
    glutDisplayFunc(render);
    glutDisplayFunc(draw);
    glutKeyboardFunc(keyboard);
    glutMainLoop();   //Finished, now render
    }

void keyboard (unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{
    GLfloat colors[][3] = { { 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f}, {1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f } };
    static int back;

    switch (key) {
    case 27: 
        exit(0);
    default:
        back ^= 1;
        glClearColor(colors[back][0], colors[back][1], colors[back][2], 1.0f);
        glutPostRedisplay();
    }
}

void render(void) {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);


    // World Snow //
    glPushMatrix(); 
    glTranslatef(0, -0.35, 0);   //Position of the shape

        glBegin(GL_POLYGON);  //Defines the type of shape
        glColor3f(1, 1,1);    //Colour of the shape 'RED, GREEN, BLUE'
        glVertex2f(-1.5,-0.7); //Vertex 2F  Gives the vertex some coords

        glColor3f(1, 1, 1);
        glVertex2f(-1.5, 0.7);

        glColor3f(1, 1, 1);
        glVertex2f( 1.5, 0.7);

        glColor3f(1, 1, 1);
        glVertex2f( 1.5,-0.7);
        glEnd();
        glPopMatrix();
        glFlush();

    // Grey gradient world
        glPushMatrix(); 
    glTranslatef(0, -0.35, 0);

        glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        glColor3f(1, 1, 1);
        glVertex2f(-1.5,-0.7);

        glColor3f(1, 1, 1);
        glVertex2f(-1.5, 0.7);

        glColor3f(0.658824, 0.658824, 0.658824);
        glVertex2f( 1.5, 0.7);

        glColor3f(1, 1, 1);
        glVertex2f( 1.5,-1.7);
        glEnd();
        glPopMatrix();
        glFlush();


    // Top of the first Tree //
    glPushMatrix(); 
    glTranslatef(-0.6, 0.5, 0);
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);  //Defines the shape as being a triangle


        glColor3f( 0.137255, 0.556863,0.137255);
        glVertex2f(-0.1, -0.1);

        glColor3f( 0.137255, 0.556863,0.137255);
        glVertex2f(0.1, -0.1);

        glColor3f( 0.137255, 0.556863,0.137255);
        glVertex2f(0.0, 0.1);
            glEnd();
        glPopMatrix();


 // Middle of the first tree


    glPushMatrix(); 
    glTranslatef(-0.6, 0.4, 0);
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);                          
        glColor3f( 0.137255, 0.556863,0.137255);
        glVertex2f(-0.1, -0.1);

        glColor3f( 0.137255, 0.556863,0.137255);
        glVertex2f(0.1, -0.1);

        glColor3f( 0.137255, 0.556863,0.137255);
        glVertex2f(0.0, 0.1);

    glEnd();
    glPopMatrix();


    // Bottom of the first tree

    glPushMatrix(); 
    glTranslatef(-0.6, 0.3, 0);
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);                           
        glColor3f( 0.137255, 0.556863,0.137255);
        glVertex2f(-0.1, -0.1);

        glColor3f( 0.137255, 0.556863,0.137255);
        glVertex2f(0.1, -0.1);

        glColor3f( 0.137255, 0.556863,0.137255);
        glVertex2f(0.0, 0.1);

    glEnd();
    glPopMatrix();
    glFlush();


    //Stump of first tree

    glPushMatrix(); 
    glTranslatef(-0.6, 0.16, 0);

    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        glColor3f( 0.36, 0.25, 0.20);
        glVertex2f(-0.02,-0.04);

        glColor3f( 0.36, 0.25, 0.20);
        glVertex2f(-0.02, 0.04);                          

        glColor3f( 0.647059, 0.164706, 0.164706);
        glVertex2f( 0.02, 0.04);

        glColor3f( 0.36, 0.25, 0.20);
        glVertex2f( 0.02,-0.04);


    glEnd();
    glPopMatrix();

    // Large Tree TOP
        glPushMatrix(); 
    glTranslatef(-0.2, 0, 0);
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);                           
        glColor3f( 0.137255, 0.556863,0.137255);
        glVertex2f(-0.15, -0.15);

        glColor3f( 0.137255, 0.556863,0.137255);
        glVertex2f(0.15, -0.15);

        glColor3f( 0.137255, 0.556863,0.137255);
        glVertex2f(0.0, 0.15);

    glEnd();
    glPopMatrix();
    glFlush();

    //Large Tree MIDDLE
    glPushMatrix(); 
    glTranslatef(-0.2, -0.15, 0);
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);                           
        glColor3f( 0.137255, 0.556863,0.137255);
        glVertex2f(-0.15, -0.15);

        glColor3f( 0.137255, 0.556863,0.137255);;
        glVertex2f(0.15, -0.15);

        glColor3f( 0.137255, 0.556863,0.137255);
        glVertex2f(0.0, 0.15);

    glEnd();
    glPopMatrix();
    glFlush();

    //Large Tree Bottom
    glPushMatrix(); 
    glTranslatef(-0.2, -0.30, 0);
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);                           
        glColor3f( 0.137255, 0.556863,0.137255);
        glVertex2f(-0.15, -0.15);

        glColor3f( 0.137255, 0.556863,0.137255);
        glVertex2f(0.15, -0.15);

        glColor3f( 0.137255, 0.556863,0.137255);
        glVertex2f(0.0, 0.15);

    glEnd();
    glPopMatrix();
    glFlush();

    //Smaller tree Top
    glPushMatrix(); 
    glTranslatef(0.05, 0.45, 0);
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);                           
        glColor3f( 0.137255, 0.556863,0.137255);
        glVertex2f(-0.05, -0.05);

        glColor3f( 0.137255, 0.556863,0.137255);
        glVertex2f(0.05, -0.05);

        glColor3f( 0.137255, 0.556863,0.137255);
        glVertex2f(0.0, 0.05);

    glEnd();
    glPopMatrix();
    glFlush();

    //Smaller tree MIDDLE
    glPushMatrix(); 
    glTranslatef(0.05, 0.40, 0);
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);                           
        glColor3f( 0.137255, 0.556863,0.137255);
        glVertex2f(-0.05, -0.05);

        glColor3f( 0.137255, 0.556863,0.137255);
        glVertex2f(0.05, -0.05);

        glColor3f( 0.137255, 0.556863,0.137255);
        glVertex2f(0.0, 0.05);

    glEnd();
    glPopMatrix();
    glFlush();

    //smaller tree bottom
        glPushMatrix(); 
    glTranslatef(0.05, 0.50, 0);
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);                           
        glColor3f( 0.137255, 0.556863,0.137255);
        glVertex2f(-0.05, -0.05);

        glColor3f( 0.137255, 0.556863,0.137255);
        glVertex2f(0.05, -0.05);

        glColor3f(0.32, 0.49, 0.46);
        glVertex2f(0.0, 0.05);

    glEnd();
    glPopMatrix();
    glFlush();

    //Stump of smaller tree
    glPushMatrix(); 
    glTranslatef(0.05, 0.32, 0);
        glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        glColor3f( 0.36, 0.25, 0.20);
        glVertex2f(-0.01,-0.03);

        glColor3f( 0.36, 0.25, 0.20);
        glVertex2f(-0.01, 0.03);                          

        glColor3f( 0.647059, 0.164706, 0.164706);
        glVertex2f( 0.01, 0.03);

        glColor3f( 0.36, 0.25, 0.20);
        glVertex2f( 0.01,-0.03);

        glEnd();
    glPopMatrix();

    //Stump of MAIN tree

        glPushMatrix(); 
    glTranslatef(-0.2, -0.50, 0);
        glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        glColor3f( 0.36, 0.25, 0.20);
        glVertex2f(-0.02,-0.05);

        glColor3f( 0.36, 0.25, 0.20);
        glVertex2f(-0.02, 0.05);                          

        glColor3f( 0.647059, 0.164706, 0.164706);
        glVertex2f( 0.02, 0.05);

        glColor3f( 0.36, 0.25, 0.20);
        glVertex2f( 0.02,-0.05);

        glEnd();
    glPopMatrix();

    // Red Present
    glPushMatrix(); 
    glTranslatef(0, -0.5, 0);
        glBegin(GL_POLYGON);

        glColor3f( 1, 0, 1);
        glVertex2f(-0.04,-0.05);

        glColor3f( 1, 0, 0);
        glVertex2f(-0.04, 0.05);

        glColor3f( 1, 0, 0);
        glVertex2f( 0.04, 0.05);

        glColor3f( 1, 0, 0);
        glVertex2f( 0.04,-0.05);
        glEnd();
    glPopMatrix();

    //Blue Present
    glPushMatrix(); 
    glTranslatef(-0.2, -0.7, 0);
        glBegin(GL_POLYGON);

        glColor3f( 0, 0, 1);
        glVertex2f(-0.07,-0.06);

        glColor3f( 0, 0, 1);
        glVertex2f(-0.07, 0.06);

        glColor3f( 0, 0, 1);
        glVertex2f( 0.07, 0.06);

        glColor3f( 0.196078, 0.6, 0.8);
        glVertex2f( 0.07,-0.06);
        glEnd();
    glPopMatrix();


    // BLUE Ribbon RED present VERT
        glPushMatrix(); 
    glTranslatef(0, -0.5, 0);
        glBegin(GL_POLYGON);

        glColor3f( 0, 0, 1);
        glVertex2f(-0.04,-0.01);

        glColor3f( 0, 0, 1);
        glVertex2f(-0.04, 0.01);

        glColor3f( 0, 0, 1);
        glVertex2f( 0.04, 0.01);

        glColor3f( 0, 0, 1);
        glVertex2f( 0.04,-0.01);
        glEnd();
        glPopMatrix();

        //BLUE ribbon RED present HORIZ
        glPushMatrix(); 
    glTranslatef(0, -0.5, 0);
        glBegin(GL_POLYGON);

        glColor3f( 0, 0, 1);
        glVertex2f(-0.01,-0.05);

        glColor3f( 0, 0, 1);
        glVertex2f(-0.01, 0.05);

        glColor3f( 0, 0, 1);
        glVertex2f( 0.01, 0.05);

        glColor3f( 0, 0, 1);
        glVertex2f( 0.01,-0.05);
        glEnd();
        glPopMatrix();

        //Yellow Ribbon Blue Present VERT
        glPushMatrix(); 
    glTranslatef(-0.2, -0.7, 0);
        glBegin(GL_POLYGON);

        glColor3f( 0.6, 0.8, 0.196078);
        glVertex2f(-0.07,-0.01);

        glColor3f( 0.6, 0.8, 0.196078);
        glVertex2f(-0.07, 0.01);

        glColor3f( 0.6, 0.8, 0.196078);
        glVertex2f( 0.07, 0.01);

        glColor3f( 0.6, 0.8, 0.196078);
        glVertex2f( 0.07,-0.01);
        glEnd();
        glPopMatrix();


        // BLUE present YELLOW ribbon VERT
            glPushMatrix(); 
    glTranslatef(-0.2, -0.7, 0);
        glBegin(GL_POLYGON);

        glColor3f( 0.6, 0.8, 0.196078);
        glVertex2f(-0.01,-0.06);

        glColor3f( 0.6, 0.8, 0.196078);
        glVertex2f(-0.01, 0.06);

        glColor3f( 0.6, 0.8, 0.196078);
        glVertex2f( 0.01, 0.06);

        glColor3f( 0.6, 0.8, 0.196078);
        glVertex2f( 0.01,-0.06);
        glEnd();
        glPopMatrix();


        //Sign Post
    glPushMatrix(); 
    glTranslatef(0.5, -0.1, 0);
        glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        glColor3f( 0.36, 0.25, 0.20);
        glVertex2f(-0.02,-0.25);

        glColor3f( 0.36, 0.25, 0.20);
        glVertex2f(-0.02, 0.25);                          

        glColor3f( 0.35, 0.16, 0.14);
        glVertex2f( 0.02, 0.25);

        glColor3f( 0.36, 0.25, 0.20);
        glVertex2f( 0.02,-0.25);
        glEnd();
        glPopMatrix();


        //Sign, Attatched to the post
    glPushMatrix(); 
    glTranslatef(0.5, -0.001, 0);
        glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        glColor3f( 0.36, 0.25, 0.20);
        glVertex2f(-0.15,-0.10);

        glColor3f( 0.36, 0.25, 0.20);
        glVertex2f(-0.15, 0.10);                          

        glColor3f( 0.35, 0.16, 0.14);
        glVertex2f( 0.15, 0.10);

        glColor3f( 0.36, 0.25, 0.20);
        glVertex2f( 0.15,-0.10);
        glEnd();
        glPopMatrix();

    //Moon
    glPushMatrix(); 
    glTranslatef(-0.9, 0.90, 0);
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        glColor4f( 0.90, 0.91, 0.98, 1);  //RGBA
        glVertex2f(-0.10,-0.2);

        glColor4f( 0.329412, 0.329412, 0.329412, 1);
        glVertex2f(-0.10, 0.2);                          

        glColor4f( 0.90, 0.91, 0.98, 1);
        glVertex2f( 0.10, 0.2);
        glColor4f( 0.90, 0.91, 0.98, 1);        
        glVertex2f( 0.10,-0.2);
    glEnd();
    glPopMatrix();

    //MAIN PRESENT UNDER SIGN
    glPushMatrix(); 
    glTranslatef(0.5, -0.6, 0);
        glBegin(GL_POLYGON);

        glColor3f( 0.89, 0.47, 0.20);
        glVertex2f(-0.20,-0.20);

        glColor3f( 0.89, 0.47, 0.20);
        glVertex2f(-0.20, 0.20);

        glColor3f( 0.89, 0.47, 0.20);
        glVertex2f( 0.20, 0.20);

        glColor3f( 1.0, 0.25, 0);
        glVertex2f( 0.20,-0.20);
        glEnd();
    glPopMatrix();

    //Orange Present Purple Ribbon VERT
            glPushMatrix(); 
    glTranslatef(0.5, -0.6, 0);
        glBegin(GL_POLYGON);

        glColor3f( 0.73, 0.16, 0.96);
        glVertex2f(-0.20,-0.06);

        glColor3f( 0.73, 0.16, 0.96);
        glVertex2f(-0.20, 0.06);

        glColor3f( 0.87, 0.58, 0.98);
        glVertex2f( 0.20, 0.06);

        glColor3f( 0.87, 0.58, 0.98);
        glVertex2f( 0.20,-0.06);
        glEnd();
        glPopMatrix();


        //Orange Present Purple Ribbon HORIZ
        glTranslatef(0.5, -0.6, 0);
        glBegin(GL_POLYGON);

        glColor3f( 0.87, 0.58, 0.98);
        glVertex2f(-0.06,-0.20);

        glColor3f( 0.87, 0.58, 0.98);
        glVertex2f(-0.06, 0.20);

        glColor3f( 0.73, 0.16, 0.96);
        glVertex2f( 0.06, 0.20);

        glColor3f( 0.73, 0.16, 0.96);
        glVertex2f( 0.06,-0.20);
        glEnd();
        glPopMatrix();
        glFlush();


        //'North Pole' TEXT sign
    glPushMatrix();
    glLoadIdentity();
    glTranslatef(0.360, -0.010, 0);
    glRotatef(90,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
    glColor3f( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 ); //Colour is black
    glRasterPos3i(10,100,1);

    char text[50]="North Pole";   //Text 

    for(int i=0; i<50; i++) 

    {
        glutBitmapCharacter(GLUT_BITMAP_HELVETICA_18,(int)text[i]);
    }
    glPopMatrix();

            glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

Comment: Where is your `render` and `draw` functions?

Comment: The render function is below the code I posted and I don't have a draw function should I have?

Comment: Please post your whole code, when the project is small. and well... yes? you call `glutDisplayFunc(draw)` which tells GLUT hey use the `draw` function as the Display Function.

Comment: Okay i've added the whole code as you suggested :)

Comment: Any ideas haha? can't get my head around it.

Comment: Well for one, you're setting the `glutDisplayFunc()` to the `draw()` function, but you don't seem to have a `draw()` function. Was that just a copy/paste error, or are you really setting it that way? If so, is *anything* getting drawn?

Comment: Everything comes up haha it's set to render and I have all of my shapes in render

Answer (score 0):

> trying to make it when you press **the escape key** the background colour changes into another colour.

1. Then why are you `exit()`ing when you press it? Swap your `case 27:` and `default:` logic.
2. Reset your projection/modelview matrices each time through `render()`:

   ```
   void render() 
   {
       glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

       glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION );
       glLoadIdentity();

       glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
       glLoadIdentity();
       ...
   ```
3. You also have an un-matched `glPopMatrix()` in "Orange Present Purple Ribbon HORIZ":

   ```
   //Orange Present Purple Ribbon HORIZ
   glTranslatef(0.5, -0.6, 0);
   glBegin(GL_POLYGON);

   glColor3f( 0.87, 0.58, 0.98);
   glVertex2f(-0.06,-0.20);

   glColor3f( 0.87, 0.58, 0.98);
   glVertex2f(-0.06, 0.20);

   glColor3f( 0.73, 0.16, 0.96);
   glVertex2f( 0.06, 0.20);

   glColor3f( 0.73, 0.16, 0.96);
   glVertex2f( 0.06,-0.20);
   glEnd();
   glPopMatrix();
   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ wha-hey?
   ```

Other than those things the background toggle seems to work.